# Download audio file from html with javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, audio, download

I'm trying to download an mp3 file on the click of a button, it downloads, but the file it downloads is not correct, it's a WAY smaller file than the original one (25 bytes), while the original one is 10MB.

It's my first time working with downloading stuff so I'm pretty clueless.

Here's some code:

JS function:

```
 function download(i) {
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio"+i);

    const blob = new Blob([audio], {type:"octet-steam"});

    const href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    const a = Object.assign(document.createElement("a"), {
        href, 
        style: "display:none",
        download: "myAudio.mp3",
    });
    document.body.appendChild(a);

    a.click();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(href);
    a.remove();
}
```

Audios are identified by their ID and their file name comes from the data I have in a database.
HTML/PHP

```
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
  $res = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  echo('<tbody id="tbody">
  <tr>
  <audio id="audio'.$i.'" src="mp3/'.$res["song_artist"].'-'.$res["song_title"].'.mp3"> 
  <td><button onclick="download('.$i.')">&#8628</button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>');
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this with JavaScript? Why can't you use a simple download link?

Comment: I do not know how to do that, and since each audio is individually id'd by a variable (i) I thought it'd be easier to do on javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `<audio>` elements and download buttons are both being generated by your PHP code, you shouldn't need JavaScript to do this.

Try something like this:

```
<tbody id="tbody">
<?php

for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
  $res = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $filePath = "mp3/{$res["song_artist"]}-{$res["song_title"]}.mp3";
?>
  <tr>
  <td><audio src="<?=$filePath?>"></td>
  <td><a href="<?=$filePath?>" download>&#8628</button></td>
  </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</tbody>
```

(I also moved your `<tbody>` tag outside the loop so that it includes all the rows inside it.)

Answer (score 1):

> You can try this. Here you have to provide audio file source instead of image source. I did not try this code, But i assure you to it should work!

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/javascript+download+image+from+url

Comment: I tried this, however it did not work, when I call the function, I get an error saying "(source) is not defined"
I put on the source the link that links to the mp3 file

Comment: The issue is with passing the source from the html/php to javascript and not the download itself i think